# How do I access entry_point scripts (i.e. transfer_learning.py, inference.py, etc) for SageMaker API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to understand the training and inference process that's taking place in SageMaker a little better, so forgive me if I'm mistaken. I've been working through SageMaker object detection tutorials and in each one I've seen high level functions set `entry_point` to a script. I included two functions below which set `entry_point` to "inference.py" and "transfer_learning.py", respectively, in this [JumpStart example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/jumpstart_object_detection/Amazon_JumpStart_Object_Detection.ipynb):

```py
model = Model(
    image_uri=deploy_image_uri,
    source_dir=deploy_source_uri,
    model_data=base_model_uri,
    entry_point="inference.py",
    role=aws_role,
    predictor_cls=Predictor,
    name=endpoint_name,
)
```

```py
od_estimator = Estimator(
    role=aws_role,
    image_uri=train_image_uri,
    source_dir=train_source_uri,
    model_uri=train_model_uri,
    entry_point="transfer_learning.py",
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type=training_instance_type,
    max_run=360000,
    hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
    output_path=s3_output_location,
    base_job_name=training_job_name,
    metric_definitions=training_metric_definitions,
)
```

Questions I have are:

1. Are these default files stored somewhere in the SDK?
2. If so, is there some way to access them?

Based on the [API docs](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html), it states that `entry_point` is the "absolute or relative path to the local Python source file" which would lead me to think the answer to 1) is "No". However, each of the JumpStart examples refer to these scripts while no such scripts exist in the directories when I create the project or run it.
Furthermore, my logs from the container when running `fit` on the estimator show a `transfer_learning.py` script being invoked and no errors following it.

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.9 transfer_learning.py --batch_size 16 --beta_1 0.9 --beta_2 0.999 --early_stopping True --early_stopping_min_delta 0.0 --early_stopping_patience 5 --epochs 40 --epsilon 1e-07 --initial_accumulator_value 0.1 --learning_rate 0.002 --model_dir s3://my-bucket/model --momentum 0.9 --optimizer adam --reinitialize_top_layer Auto --rho 0.95 --train_only_top_layer True
```

I've trained and deployed multiple models (unfortunately, not object detection) where I followed a template for creating the `entry_point` script. If they exist, I'd like to access these scripts so that I could do things like use them as a starting point to improving my models instead of writing one from scratch or adding TensorBoard logging to them. I would also appreciate relevant resources to creating an `entry_point` script for object detection tasks.

Answer (score 0):

> Are these default files stored somewhere in the SDK?

Not exactly. In your Jumpstart example, you can see it [using an SDK class to fetch a public S3 URI](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/script_uris.py#L28) where the scripts are stored. That URI is being passed to the `source_dir` property on the model.

Jumpstart is simplifying things by giving you a pre-made, pre-hosted source directory with an entry point script.

> If so, is there some way to access them?

`deploy_source_uri` will have a public S3 location where you can view the scripts, but you won't be able to update them.

Jumpstart is trying to keep things simple here, but in doing so it's hiding some details. The way this usually works is that you have a local source directory (say, in your notebook instance) which contains your entry point script, dependencies, etc. You pass that local path to the model, where the SDK then does the work of uploading it to S3.

Comment: Adding to this, if you want to use your own custom entry_point  inference script, then it looks like we have to define these specifically named funcs inside `inference.py` [according to this documentation](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/xgboost_abalone/xgboost_inferenece_script_mode.html) : `input_fn`, `predict_fn`, and/or `output_fn`

Comment: So the `script_uris.retrieve()` @Payton posted was almost useful for me. I was able to get the script source from calling `sagemaker.script_uris.retrieve(region='us-west-2', model_id = "huggingface-llm-falcon-7b-bf16", model_version='*', script_scope='inference')` for my own use case, downloaded/extracted the resulting `sourcedir.tar.gz` , but the `inference.py` in there was completely blank :( I was hoping I could see how exactly they were accessing model objects/artifacts inside